# $C^0([a,b])\supsetneq D^1([a,b])\supsetneq C^1([a,b])\supsetneq D^2([a,b])\supsetneq C^2([a,b])\supsetneq\cdots$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am reading "Calculus II" by Yukio Mimura (in Japanese).

Let $C^n([a,b])$ be a set of functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is of class $C^n$.
Let $D^n([a,b]$ be a set of functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which have $n$-th derivative.

In this book, the author said that $$C^0([a,b])\supsetneq D^1([a,b])\supsetneq C^1([a,b])\supsetneq D^2([a,b])\supsetneq C^2([a,b])\supsetneq\cdots$$ holds obviously.

I don't think this is obvious.

Are the following statements right?

> Let $g(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & (x\neq 0)\\
> 0 & (x=0) \end{cases}.$
> Let $f(x) := \overbrace{\int_{a}^{x}\dots\int_{a}^{x}}^{n-1} g(t-\frac{a+b}{2}) \overbrace{dt\dots dt}^{n-1}$.
> Then, $f \in D^n([a,b])$ but $f\notin C^n([a,b])$.

> Let $f(x) := \overbrace{\int_{a}^{x}\dots\int_{a}^{x}}^{n} |t-\frac{a+b}{2}| \overbrace{dt\dots dt}^{n}$.
> Then, $f \in C^n([a,b])$ but $f\notin D^{n+1}([a,b])$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your examples are correct. Here is the way I would formalize it.

We can safely assume $a=-1$ and $b=1$. First of all, we have the proper inclusions $C^0([-1,1])\supsetneq D^1([-1,1])\supsetneq C^1([-1,1])$, provided by the examples you give, of $|x|$ and $x^2\sin(1/x)$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, differentiation provides bijections $C^{n+1}\to C^n\times\mathbb R$, sending $f\mapsto (f',f(0))$, and similarly for $D^{n+1}\to D^n\times\mathbb R$. By repeated application of these isomorphisms, the proper inclusions $C^0\supsetneq D^1\supsetneq C^1$ translates to proper inclusions $C^n\supsetneq D^{n+1}\supsetneq C^{n+1}$, which was what we wanted.

Comment: Kenta S, Thank you very much for your answer!